# Counting the same column of different value sets in a single group by clause

Tags: sqlite

I have a table (SQLite DB) like this,

`CREATE TABLE parser (ip text, user text, code text);`

Now I need to count how many `code` have a value of either `1, 2, or 3`, and how many are not, group by `ip` field.

But as far as I can go, I can't do this altogether, but with two SQL phrases.

e.g

```
select count(*) as cnt, ip 
from parser 
where code in (1, 2, 3) 
group by ip 
order by cnt DESC 
limit 10
```

And a `not in` query.

So, can I merge the two queries into a single one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will you give you two counts per `ip`, one for the rows where `code` has values 1, 2 or 3 and another count for all the rest (everything but 1, 2, 3, including `NULL`.)

```
SELECT ip,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_in, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code IN (1, 2, 3) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS cnt_rest
FROM parser  
GROUP BY ip 
ORDER BY cnt_in DESC ;
```

This will you give you 3 counts, one for 1,2,3, another for the rest of integer values and a third for rows that have `NULL` in `code`:

```
SELECT ip,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 END) AS cnt_in, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code NOT IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 END) AS cnt_not_in,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS cnt_null
FROM parser  
GROUP BY ip 
ORDER BY cnt_in DESC ;
```

---

If you want to limit the first result (as your code) to the top 10 rows and the second result to the other top 10 rows, you can use two subqueries and a `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ip,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
         'in' AS type
  FROM parser
  WHERE code IN (1, 2, 3)
  GROUP BY ip 
  ORDER BY cnt DESC 
  LIMIT 10 
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ip,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
         'not in' AS type
  FROM parser
  WHERE code NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
  GROUP BY ip 
  ORDER BY cnt DESC 
  LIMIT 10 
) ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feb760/1)**